# How to declare a value passed by jquery in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

So i need to declare my value which i am passing with ajax in php,because when i use for example `if(!empty($_POST["fsearch"]))` it shows nothing and when i put `$fsearch=$_POST['fsearch'];`it gives me Undefined Index error.I have variable search_term in jquery which passes value to "fsearch" in php(which is also name of my input field).
I don't know how to declare this value which comming from Jquery into PHP..
There is code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
        var search_term =$(this).val();
  console.log(search_term);
        $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"/Food-Search",
         data:{fsearch:search_term},
         success:function(res){
          $("#food_search_result").html(res);
          console.log(res);
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
       });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                            HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<form method="POST">
    <p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                            PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["fsearch"])) { 
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
?>
```

So I need to define the 'fsearch' as value coming from jquery.
And check if input field with name "fsearch" is empty.
Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#food_search").on('blur',function(){ //blur event ...triggres when input field is unfoused
        var search_term =$(this).val();
        console.log(search_term);
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/Food-Search.php",//if you are not using .htaccess or routing give file name with .php extension
    data:{fsearch:search_term},
    success:function(res){
        $("#food_search_result").html(res);
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: it would be better to explain the answer. The change is not obvious, and OP might not understand why.